# overloading [][] in c#

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I'm building a tree-based data structure and overloaded [ ] so that I can say

```
node["key1", "key2", "key3"]
```

which returns the node whose parents 1, 2, and 3 levels above are the nodes with those keys. the nodes conceptually map to an array of data, so what I have now is this function:

```
node[keys...].SetValue(i, value)
```

which sets the i-th value in the node's data. what would be nice is if I could do this:

```
node[keys][i] = value
```

problem is, node[keys] returns a node, so the [i] indexing tries to get at another node. basically what I want to be able to do is overload "[ ][ ]" as an operator, which I can't.

is there any way to get at what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note: **This answer talks about implementing something like `obj[a][b][c]...` that could work with variable number of brackets. It seems it's not exactly what the OP wanted**.

You can't overload that directly. You should return an object with an indexer from the first indexer so that you could simulate this functionality.
It's a bit harder to simulate `set` but it's possible to do something like:

```
public class Node<T> {
    public Node<T> this[string key] {
        get { return GetChildNode(key); }
        set {
            if (value is DummyNode<T>) {
                GetChildNode(key).Value = value.Value;
            } else {
                // do something, ignore, throw exception, depending on the problem
            }
        }
    } 
    public static implicit operator T(Node<T> value) {
        return value.Value;
    }
    private class DummyNode<T> : Node<T> {
    }
    public static implicit operator Node<T>(T value) {
        return new DummyNode<T> { Value = value };
    }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In fact, there is no [][] operator. It always just applies [] the the next object, as with jagged arrays.

Comment: In fact, technically, in C#, [] is not an "operator" at all.

Comment: Seems like my answer is completely irrelevant to the question :) I thought the question wants to change [x,y,z] to [x][y][z]. I'll leave it here though, if someone needs to do that kind of thing.

Comment: In fact, technically, in C#, [] _is_ an operator. Why would you suppose that it is not? (It is not classified as an _overloadable_ operator but it is classified as an operator.)

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Thanks for the correction. Indeed, "overloadable operator" is what I should have said in the above sentence (the term used in the spec). To clarify what I meant: I was trying to say you can't overload it as you would in C++ and declaring an indexer does not count as overloading [].

Answer (score 4):

seems I just needed to tinker a bit more to figure it out...I created a second overload:

```
public object this[int index]
{
    set { ... }
}
```

which now lets me do

```
node["child1", "child1's child1"][i] = value
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
var pat = new Tree<string[]>();
pat["test", "test2", "test3"] = new[] { "test3" };
Console.WriteLine(pat["test", "test2", "test3"][0]);
```

Magic classes are fun...

```
public class Tree<T>
{
    private Dictionary<string, T> _store = new Dictionary<string, T>();

    private string GetKey(string[] index)
    {
        if (index == null || index.Length == 0) return string.Empty;
        return string.Join(".", index);
    }

    public T this[params string[] index]
    {
        get
        {
            var key = GetKey(index);
            if (!_store.ContainsKey(key))
                return default(T);
            return _store[key];
        }
        set
        {
            var key = GetKey(index);
            if (_store.ContainsKey(key))
                _store.Remove(key);
            if (value != null)
                _store.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```